# Make even and odd threads to print numbers in natural order in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I know this question has been asked before, But I am unable to figure out why my solution is not working for me. I have two threads even and odd, one prints even numbers and other prints odd numbers. When I start the threads I want the output to be in natural order of numbers like 0 1 2 3..etc. This is my code:-
[updated]

```
public class ThreadCommunication {


public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException
{
    final ThreadCommunication obj = new ThreadCommunication();
    Thread even = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
                synchronized(obj){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    try {
                        obj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread odd = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<10;i=i+2){
                synchronized(obj){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }

        }
    };
    even.start();
    odd.start();
}
```

}

when I run the above code, sometimes it prints the numbers in natural order as expected but sometimes it prints in some other order for ex:

```
0
1
3
5
7
9
2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

```
volatile static boolean isAlreadyWaiting = false;



Thread even = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        try {
                            if (!isAlreadyWaiting) {
                                isAlreadyWaiting = true;
                                obj.wait();
                            }
                            obj.notify();
                            isAlreadyWaiting=false;

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread odd = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        try {
                            if(isAlreadyWaiting){
                            obj.notify();
                            isAlreadyWaiting = false;
                            }
                            if (!isAlreadyWaiting) {
                                isAlreadyWaiting = true;
                                obj.wait();
                            }

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Check documentation

> **public class IllegalMonitorStateException extends RuntimeException**
>
> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to **wait** on an object's
>   monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor
>   without owning the specified monitor.

Monitor is owned by `obj`

So  you should call

```
obj.wait();
```

and

```
obj.notify();
```

For more info on Ownership

> This methods (wait or notify) should only be called by a thread that
>   is the owner of this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of
>   the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> 1. By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> 2. By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes
>      on the object.
>
>    3. For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method
>         of that class.

**Only one thread at a time can own an object's monitor.**

Comment: Your answer helped me eliminate the exception, but I am still not able to get the proper output as expected. I have updated the code.

Comment: @Surajhk You should place `try {
                     obj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }` this code outside for loop because your prevous code wil l print one even number and then, your even thread will be on wait

Comment: The out put that i am expecting is 0123456789

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera, this code will deadlock if the second thread gets the lock first. It also doesn't account for spurious wakeups.

Comment: @shmosel yes that's 
correct.. I could write a my own code for that but I have tried to fix his code, u could see I haven't wrote any new code because he is a learner, let him mean
Learn its not a production code that I should concerned about. But I think that is out of scope of this question ..

Comment: I will possibly update answer when I was with
 my PC ( I am typing with thumbs on my mobile)

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera, spurious wakeups may be outside the scope of OP's question. But the deadlock is pretty serious and very plausible.

Comment: @shmosel check my edit,  I could make it easily with Concurrency classes and I have n number of solutions for this problem, but I would not really want to change his code, I want him to learn things practically by himself( like Deadlocks, Starvation etc). Because the best way to avoid mistakes is to anticipate them

Comment: Got `1023456789` as output, you should force `even` thread to start before the `odd` one. The issue is just related to the first number printed by each thread, they work fine starting from `2`. EDIT: Moving the `println` after the `try{} catch{}` should be enough.

Comment: @StepTNT This will force first thread to start first `even.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
  odd.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);`

Comment: Check the edit to my comment, there's no need to use priorities.

Answer (score 0):

@Pragnani Kinnera is right about the exception you're seeing. But if you want to alternate between `even` and `odd`, you'll need to move your second synchronized block into the loop. Otherwise, the notifying thread will hold the lock exclusively until the loop completes. (As opposed to the first thread, which yields its lock on each round.)

```
Thread odd = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        for(int i=1;i<10;i=i+2){
            synchronized(obj){
                System.out.println(i);
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The first thread, however, *should* have the loop inside the synchronized block. If both threads release the lock, they both have an equal chance at reacquiring it. But if the first loop is inside the synchronized block, the second thread won't be able to reenter until the first has completed a full round and is waiting once again.

EDIT: This still won't work correctly, because there is no guarantee that the first thread won't reacquire the lock before the second thread does, per this quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()):

> The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object.

You'll probably want to wake and notify from both threads to ensure they're in sync.

Comment: I am still unable to get the expected output consistently. I have updated the question

Comment: @Surajhk what is your expected output ? `123456789` ?

Comment: My expected output is 0123456789

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution:

```
public class ThreadCommunication {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final ThreadCommunication obj = new ThreadCommunication();
        Thread even = new Thread("Even Thread"){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                for(int i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
                    System.out.println(i);

                    synchronized(obj){

                        obj.notify();
                    }
                    synchronized(obj){
                        try {
                            obj.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        Thread odd = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                for(int i=1;i<10;i=i+2){
                    try {
                        synchronized(obj){
                            obj.wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(i);
                    synchronized(obj){
                        obj.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        even.start();
        odd.start();
    }

}
```

As explained by @shmosel, your synchronized block should only contain code that need to be synchronized.